# Passing parameterized build parameter to Jython plugin in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jython

I need to

- run a parameterized build
- have Jython script (provided by Jython plugin) to get the parameters (I have defined Jython script as build step in the parameterized build)

In a shell script build step params can easily be accessed using env variables. Do I have to do the same in Jython? (can I do it at all)?

Comment: Are you using `Execute Jython script` in `Build` section?

Comment: @Technext: yes, at this moment, although other solutions might do as well of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how you can access the variable from Parameterized parameter in `Execute Jython script` in `Build` section but if i run the Jython script in Windows (after selecting `Execute Windows batch command` option from the dropdown list in `Build` section), it works fine. Check the snapshots below where i have used [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) for creating a *String Parameter* and then using the same in Jython script. It works fine and displays the value of the variable in output.

[image]

[image]

Here's the sample script i used for accepting parameter:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

For *nix environment, you obviously have to select `Execute shell` in `Build` section's dropdown list and also change `%var%` to `$var`.